# Why is this GuiControl not updating my gui every cycle?

Tags: autohotkey

Here is the pertinent code:

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance, Force
#NoEnv

Gui, 2:New
Gui, 2: +Owner
Gui, 2:Color, 000000
Gui, 2:+hwndGUIaddress2
Gui, 2:Show, w500 h137, WinB
Gui, 2: +LastFound
WinSet, Transparent, 190

Gui, New
Gui, +Owner
Gui, Font, s8 cB4FFFF, Tahoma
Gui, Add, Text, x5  y5  w130, Filename:
;Gui, Add, Text, vProgress
Gui, Add, Text, x80 y5  w650 vFilename
Gui, Add, Text,     y+1 w650 vProgress

Gui, Color, EEAA99
Gui, +LastFound
Gui, +hwndGUIAddress1
WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99 225
Gui,    Show, w500 h137
OnMessage(0x03, "WM_MOVE")

Loop, D:\MOVIES_in\*.ts,0,1
{
    title = %A_LoopFileFullPath%
    LongPath = %A_LoopFileLongPath%
    SplitPath LongPath, FileName, OutDir, OutExtension, OutNameNoExt, OutDrive
    FileGetSize, Size_In, %A_LoopFileFullPath%
}


GuiControl, , Filename, %title%

Gosub Check_D_Drive

SetTimer, Check_D_Drive, 5000
return

Check_D_Drive:
{
    Loop, D:\MOVIES_out\*.ts,0,1
    {
        FileGetSize, Size_Out, %A_LoopFileFullPath%
    }

    sleep 5000

    Loop, D:\MOVIES_out\*.ts,0,1
    {
        FileGetSize, Size_Out2, %A_LoopFileFullPath%
    }

    complete:= Size_Out / Size_In
    msgbox,,,%complete%,1
    GuiControl,, Progress, %complete%

    if (  complete > .98 )
    {
        if (%Size_Out% == %Size_Out2%)
        {
            SetTimer, Check_I_Drive, Off
            msgbox Job is complete
        }
    }
}
return
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WM_MOVE()
{
    global GUIAddress1, global GUIAddress2
    WinGetPos, mainX, mainY, Width, Height, Ahk_id %GUIAddress1%
    WinMove, Ahk_id %GUIAddress2%,, %mainX%, %mainY%
    WinSet, AlwaysOnTop,, Ahk_id %GUIAddress1%
}
```

Msgbox works fine. I'm just not seeing the update in my GUI.

Comment: Please post the exact code you run, including the variable defintions of `title` and `completion`. The way I see it, the statement `GuiControl, , Completion, %completion%` updates the `Completion` control with its own value.

Comment: don't think it's a variable problem... the msgbox shows the variable being updated properly

Answer (score 0):

If you limit your problem to just the updating, it works

```
Gui, New
Gui, +Owner
Gui, Font, s8 cB4FFFF, Tahoma
Gui, Add, Text, x5  y5  w130, Filename:
;Gui, Add, Text, vProgress
Gui, Add, Text, x80 y5  w650 vFilename
Gui, Add, Text,     y+1 w650 vProgress
Gui, Show


loop, 100
{
  Random, Size_Out , 1000000, 100000000
  Random, Size_In , 1000000, 100000000

  complete:= Size_Out / Size_In
  GuiControl,, Filename, %A_Index%
  GuiControl,, Progress, %complete%
  Sleep, 1000

}
```

Your problem has to be somewhere else.

Testing with a MsgBox is problematic, because it
changes the focus and the runtime of the loop.

While searching for the problem instead of MsgBox, 
you could try to display
the value of *complete* with a tooltip to check
if it is really updating.

```
Tooltip, %complete%
```

Another reason for your problem is that you run **two** GUIs
at the same time (can't judge from your script, but you 
have a 2nd GUI in there).

If this is your problem and the tooltip shows the correct value, 
look at this [example](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/89479-2-guis-1-focus/) on how to name the guis and how to update 
a specific one.

Comment: I had tooltip updating just fine. That's when I decided to upgrade to a real GUI. And now this sadness occurs. I also commented out one GUI to try and make it work. It still didn't update my numbers. Maybe I should just rewrite my timer as a while loop. Thanks for the link though. I'll study that.